# Nginx headers cause invalid JSON, I think

Tags: php, json, nginx, gzip, fastcgi

I have recently moved from Lighttpd to Nginx and while everything seems speedy and good, JSON output is invalid.

At least that's what I think and when I test it, [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says

> syntax error, unexpected TINVALID at line 1

when I test my JSON output: http://bit.ly/fLCxox

I have tested internally that the data is ok by `var_dump(json_decode(json_encode(data)));`

Here's my [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/881185).

Any help would be great.

thx, Jacob

Comment: It would probably help if you could post the actual JSON that seems to be invalid. (And preferrably some more info about how you produce it.)  The `default_type text/html;` for your php upstream provider might be the problem. Post the raw data that the server sends to give people a chance to help.

Comment: Here's the JSON, which isn't the problem: {"error":"Invalid ID"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `0.json` file contain three zero bytes in the beginning.

```
00000000  00 00 00 7b 22 65 72 72  6f 72 22 3a 22 49 6e 76  |...{"error":"Inv|
00000010  61 6c 69 64 20 49 44 22  7d                       |alid ID"}|
```

Comment: Any idea how I can find out why that happens?

Comment: It seems to be the case for Php output while static looks fine, so my assumption is that it is caused by the connection between Nginx and php-fpm as the other server running Lighttpd with the same code doesn't have the problem.

Comment: It seems to be CakePHP related as a simple php and json file doesn't have the problem.